# Difftime between rows inconsistent

Tags: r, date, difftime

I want to calculate the day-difference between two rows (per ID) with difftime. At the beginning I get the right results but in some lines there are inconsistent values:

```
PatId Date Tage
3l 2015-02-10 NA
3l 2015-03-30 48
3l 2015-06-03 65
```

...

```
5r 2016-02-02 NA
5r 2016-03-01 62
5r 2016-03-29 -469
```

this is my function:

```
setDT(AllPat)[, Tage := difftime(AllPat$Date, shift(AllPat$Date), units = "days"), by = PatID]
```

I tried it already with tz="GMT", but it doesn't change, maybe someone has an idea?

Have anyone an idea how I can change the function to calculate the difference and write it always in the first row, so that the last row has only a NA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not call `AllPat$Date` in the data table command and expect your program to split it by PatID. Your program currently tries to use the whole vector `AllPat$Date` for every ID. You need to refer to the Date variable in the data table so that the program can work with Date and PatID together if that makes sense.

I would convert your `data.frame` to a `data.table` first to preserve as much as possible your code

```
dtAllPat=as.data.table(AllPat)
dtAllPat[, Tage := difftime(Date, shift(Date), units = "days"), keyby = .(PatID)]
```

Comment: Do you know how I can change the function to calculate the difference and write it always in the first row, so that the last row of an ID has only a NA?

Comment: `AllPat[, Tage := lead(as.numeric(difftime(Date, shift(Date), units = "days"))), keyby = .(PatID)]`

Comment: `Lead` does the opposite of `shift` and I has to convert to numeric first to apply `lead`